# Can't make a holiday vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame (creatively named data1) that contains daily data.  I need a column of holidays if that row (day) is a holiday.  The column date is formatted as a date and the column and YEAR is a factor ;

```
> str(data1$date)
 Date[1:3645], format: "2007-09-06" "2007-09-07"
```

I have loaded the timeDate package and was hoping to use it.  I tried the following as an example;

```
data1$holiday[data1$date == USDecorationMemorialDay(year = data1$YEAR)] <- "memday"
```

However I get this error message;

```
Error in `==.default`(data1$date, USDecorationMemorialDay(year = data1$YEAR)) : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, data1$date == USDecorationMemorialDay(year = data1$YEAR),  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In Ops.factor(year, 10000) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

edit:

Here is the dput of my data frame;

```
> dput(droplevels(head(data1[c("date", "holiday", "YEAR")])))
structure(list(date = structure(c(13762, 13763, 13764, 13765, 
13766, 13767), class = "Date"), holiday = c("NO", "NO", "NO", 
"NO", "NO", "NO"), YEAR = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("date", 
"holiday", "YEAR"), row.names = 6:11, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You seem to be using `USDecorationMemorialDay()` as a function. What package is that from?

Comment: it is a function from the timeDate package

Comment: Is your `holiday` column a factor? I would recommend keeping it as `character` until you are done modifying it. If you still have problems, try converting your `year` column to an integer - the help page for `?holidayDate` says that the year argument should be *"an integer value or vector of year numbers including the century"* - suggesting that it should be an integer, not a factor.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. I made your suggested changes and now get a different error message;
Error in `==.default`(data1$date, USDecorationMemorialDay(year = data1$YEAR)) : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
In addition: Warning message:
In whichFormat(charvec[1]) :
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Need better description of the data1 object. Why not post at a minimum `str(data1)` but better would be to post a small segment of the data1 using `dput(head(data1))`

Comment: here are the results of str(data1);
'data.frame': 3645 obs. of  37 variables:
 $ YearQuarter    : num  2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 ...
 $ YearMonth      : Factor w/ 120 levels "2007M09","2007M10",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ date           : Date, format: "2007-09-06" "2007-09-07" "2007-09-08" "2007-09-09" ...
 $ datetimestr    : int  2007090615 2007090715 2007090814 2007090919 2007091014 2007091114 2007091219 2007091319 2007091414 2007091510 ...
 $ YEAR           : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ holiday        : chr  "NO" "NO" "NO" "NO" ...

Comment: Please edit things like this into your question and use the code formatting to make them readable. And with the `dput`, try `dput(droplevels(head(data1[c("date, holiday", "YEAR")])))` which will just give the relevant columns. Put the entire result into your question.

Comment: will do.  Thank you